# tshark 2.2.6 doesn't display data.text field on some computer

Tags: linux, udp, wireshark, netcat, tshark

I want to capture and display the UDP traffic on a certain port using `tshark`. I want to display the text content on each captured line.

I have two computers both running CentOS 7. I built from sources latest Wireshark 2.2.6 following the tutorial here: http://blog.jeffli.me/blog/2016/08/14/build-latest-wireshark-in-centos-7/

I installed the resulting RPMs on both computers. After that I ran (as root) the following `tshark` command on both computers:

```
/usr/local/bin/tshark -f "port 3901" -i any -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data.text
```

Then I ran the following on **computer A** (that's my desktop computer, running CentOS 7 in graphical mode):

```
echo "test message" | nc -u 192.168.224.60 3901
```

`tshark` showed the following line:

```
1   Apr 24, 2017 14:05:25.926688950 EEST    192.168.224.60  192.168.224.60  test message
```

That's exactly what I need.

Now.. I did exactly the same test on **computer B** (this is the remote computer running CentOS 7 in text mode), just the IP is different there.

`tshark` refuses to display the `data.text` field. It outputs a line like this, without `data.text` field:

```
1   Apr 24, 2017 11:06:19.947384620 UTC 192.168.0.60    192.168.0.60
```

I'm using the same `nc` version (6.4) on both computers.

I have no idea what could cause this different behavior of computer **A** vs **B**. What could prevent `tshark` on computer **B** from displaying the `date.text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer on another forum: 
https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/61023/tshark-226-doesnt-display-datatext-field-on-some-computer

The solution was to add the following parameter to my command:

```
-o data.show_as_text:TRUE
```

So the command became:

```
/usr/local/bin/tshark -f "port 3901" -i any -o data.show_as_text:TRUE -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data.text
```

This way I had the date.text properly displayed on any computer.